# How To Add Border Radius For Call To Action Element In Elementor

Tags: css, elementor

Today I was adding a Call To Action element in elementor and I set an image as the background and I changed the border radius to 5 (Under advanced> border> radius) and the border appears rounded on the editor and the preview but when I view the page from my device (iPhone) the image in the call to action is not rounded like it appears in the editor or preview. I tried playing around with it and I figured out that the border will apply if you have a color as a background of the call to action but will not apply if you have an image as a background. I've had the same issue before with the Slides Widget however I was able to resolve this by using some CSS
`selector .swiper-slide-bg, selector .elementor-background-overlay {  border-radius: 20px!important; }`
,that I found on this article: https://mcstarters.com/blog/add-border-radius-to-the-elementor-slider-element/ . I then tried to create my own code:

```
selector .elementor-cta-background-overlay { 
    border-radius: 20px!important;
}
```

But this did not solve the issue. This is not a plugin or theme conflict I created brand new websites with nothing but Elemntor and pro installed and still had the same result. If anyone is able to figure this I would GREATLY appreciate it as I've spent HOURS online trying to find some CSS to solve this with no luck. Even reached out to Elemntor support out of desperation but even THEY can't figure it out. Any CSS Code Would be appreciated thanks.

[These Are Some Images To Help]
[What Elemntor Preview Looks Like]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7DiF.jpg
[What it looks like on my Device]: https://www.icloud.com/photos/#0e6G2hxKFShWs5dENCe5VGfpg

Comment: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/249

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.elementor-cta .elementor-cta__bg-wrapper { 
border-radius: 12px!important;
}
```